# Save log analytic query to storage account using Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, kql

We have a large data set and we need to save a filtered amount of data to a storage account. We could do a function app once the data hits the storage account but it would be easier to filter it by the query we have on the dashboard and save that to a storage account.

Basically we'd like to save the kusto query to azure storage account.

Is that possible and would anyone know how I could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to save the output of the query, I would say the easiest way is by creating an Azure Logic Apps and Use Kusto connector + Blob Connector. Basically you'll specify the query, and persist the output to a blob:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/tools/logicapps

Comment: Thanks for that, what reoccurence frequency would this run at, would it trigger whenever the query was run and would it update the storage account with the incremental change or would it do a full export of the data again? Sorry if this sounds silly not great with kusto and logic apps

Comment: No silly questions, silly is not to ask if it's not clear. So the Azure Logic Apps trigger will be recurrency, it means you'll specify the interval. It can be every 10 seconds, every 10 minutes, every 6 hours, every 2 days, etc.. Once it triggers, it will return the output to you, it means it's not smart enough to do the diff since the last trigger.